# Javac is not same version as java

Tags: java, linux-mint-19

Linux Mint 19.3

In file **etc/profile**:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

run `set` in terminal:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251/bin
```

In terminal run

```
java -version

java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

It's correct.

But when I run

`javac -version` I get another version.

```
javac 11.0.7
```

I need javac to be version **1.8** (same as java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause of the problem is due to **JAVA_HOME being added at the end of the PATH**.

---

The problem can be fixed by ***adding JAVA_HOME to beginning of PATH***, as follows:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**Working example:**

Suppose that JDK 11 is installed in **/opt/jdk-11** directory.
Here are the steps to use java version 11 for both java and javac:

**1. Update JAVA_HOME and PATH**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**2. Verify that both java and javac are picked from /opt/jdk-11/bin**

```
$ which java
/opt/jdk-11/bin/java

$ which javac
/opt/jdk-11/bin/javac
```

**3. Verify the output of java and javac**

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 11.0.7
```